# clear submit failed after the user makes a change in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have the following component rendered in a redux-form:

```
export const renderFormInput = ({
  input: { onChange, value },
  meta: { active, error, invalid, submitFailed },
  ...rest
}) =>
  <FormInput
    invalid={!active && invalid && submitFailed}
    errorMessage={!active && invalid && error}
    onChange={onChange}
    {...rest}
  />;
```

This all works great but what I would like is to not show any error message until the user tries to submit again.

The only way I can think of doing this is to set `submitFailed` to be false somehow.  Is this possible or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to give a complete answer without the surrounding context. Usually, the best way is to have a variable saying whether a submission has been attempted or not. For example, you could have a `fieldIsPristine` and use that to control whether the errors are displayed or not. You then would toggle that in the onSubmit function. You could do the same with your submitFailed field as well.

If you're wanting to avoid handling that variable at the top level you can just have an intermediate function that catches the submit and toggles the state then passes it up if it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

See the discussion here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2868

You can reset `submitFailed` via the `stopSubmit` action.